# Google Maps marker icon (symbol) not rotating

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I posted a question yesterday which was resolved by a typographical correction, but now I have a problem which is baffling me.

I have a custom marker on a map, using a symbol as the icon so that I can rotate it. When I initialise it I set rotation to be 0, and at some point will call the `updateMap()` function which should give the marker a new rotation value. And it does, I'm able to see by printing the marker and its icon in the console that the rotation has changed, but the marker remains staunchly pointed north.

Here's my code for initialising and rotating the marker:

```
var map;
var marker;

function initMap(position) {
    var map_div = document.getElementById("map");
    map = new google.maps.Map(map_div, {
        zoom: 14,
        center: { lat: position.Latitude, lng: position.Longitude },
        mapTypeId: 'terrain'
    });
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: map.getCenter(),
        map: map,
        title: "MY MARKER",
        icon: {
            path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,
            scale: 4,
            strokeColor: '#00F',
            rotation: 0,
        }
    });
}

function updateMap() {
    var bearing = 135;
    console.log(bearing);
    marker.icon.rotation = bearing;
    console.log(marker);
}
```

The console tells me that the rotation of the marker has changed but the marker itself does not change direction.

**Things I have tried:**

- Triggering a `resize` event at the end of the update map function
- Not specifying an original rotation for the icon
- Switching the rotations, so starting at 135 and trying to change to 0 (the value of the marker's rotation at `marker.icon.rotation` after calling `updateMap()` becomes 0 but the actual marker keeps pointing at 135)
- Changing the rotation right at the end of the `initMap()` function - this *does* work, which leads me to believe that there's something not right about the `updateMap()` function. I can't figure out what though, it still executes the function. Logging the marker in the global scope also tells me that the rotation has changed.

Any ideas or suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no documented `icon` property of a [google.maps.Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker) object (while it may "work", using undocumented properties is not recommended).  Use the documented setters and getters to get the value, change it, then set it again:

```
function updateMap() {
    var bearing = 135;
    console.log(bearing);
    var icon = marker.getIcon();
    icon.rotation = bearing;
    marker.setIcon(icon);
    console.log(marker);
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/6o0u4g6q/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
var marker;

function initMap(position) {
  var map_div = document.getElementById("map");
  map = new google.maps.Map(map_div, {
    zoom: 14,
    center: {
      lat: position.Latitude,
      lng: position.Longitude
    },
    mapTypeId: 'terrain'
  });
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: map.getCenter(),
    map: map,
    title: "MY MARKER",
    icon: {
      path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,
      scale: 4,
      strokeColor: '#00F',
      rotation: 0,
    }
  });
}

function updateMap(bearing) {
  var icon = marker.getIcon();
  icon.rotation = bearing;
  marker.setIcon(icon);
}

function initialize() {
  initMap({
    Latitude: 37.4419,
    Longitude: -122.1419
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<input type="button" value="rotate" onclick="updateMap(parseInt(document.getElementById('rotation').value));" /><input id="rotation" value="135" />
<div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can just change `updateMap` function to:

```
function updateMap() {
  var bearing = 135;
  console.log(marker.icon);
  marker.icon.rotation = bearing;
  marker.setMap(map);
  console.log(marker.icon);
}
```

`marker.setMap(map);` re-adds to the map after the options are updated

**JSFiddle** : https://jsfiddle.net/q3wjrpdw/8/